# Jaeger distritubed tracing with application integrated with 3rd party APIs

Tags: microservices, jaeger, opentracing, distributed-tracing

Currently analysing a probable distributed tracing tool for our Event Driven Microservice architecture.

Which currently looks somewhat similar to the picture below.
[image]

As I understand all the application integrated with jaeger(spring boot application having the proper jaeger dependancies) would create a span based on the middleware in place in my case mostly kafka.

My question is if on the chain of calls somewhere there is an application that calls lets a 3rd party API which has no jaeger tracing integrated in it. Would it break the tracing the chain?

Or lets say if the main application chain uses kafka to communicate within the services how to make sure that the tracing is not interrupted?

Should one write custom code for this, unfortunately I couldn't find an answer to this in their docs. https://www.jaegertracing.io/docs/1.36/getting-started/

Answer (score 1):

> My question is if on the chain of calls somewhere there is an
> application that calls lets a 3rd party API which has no jaeger
> tracing integrated in it. Would it break the tracing the chain?

In the setup that you have described above the calls to third parties would potentially not appear on the traces. But they will not break the chain. For example the second "jaeger integrated" app on your list is making 2 outgoing calls here. To a third party and to another instrumented application. The call to the other instrumented apps (and downstream apps) should definitely appear on your jaeger graph.

The call to the third party is slightly more difficult. If you are calling via a proxy that you have access to it would be possible to add telemetry information relating to the call at that point.

The alternative, and probably easier approach, is to trace outgoing calls from the instrumented apps.